Save the variable's value after Exit-PSssession
I've been trying to solve another problem for weeks. If I'm already in a remote pssession after the command Enter-pssession. How can I save the variable's value after I Exit-pssession?
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName <RemoteServer>
Enter-PSSession -Session $session
[RemoteServer]: PS C:\Users\user\Documents> $remote_var = '3333'
[RemoteServer]: PS C:\Users\user\Documents> Exit-pssession
$remote_var = ?

I know the way
$var = Invoke-Command -ComputerName <RemoteServer> -ScriptBlock { '3333' } 

But this method does not suit me, because we are talking about that I am already constantly in a remote session

so using that $session instance you can retrieve that var using Invoke-Command -Session $session { $remote_var }

Thank you very much, I couldn't solve this problem for a week )). +1000.

As long as the PSSession is still opened you can retrieve your remote variable using Invoke-Command and passing that same session as argument:
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName <RemoteServer>
Enter-PSSession -Session $session
[RemoteServer]: PS C:\Users\user\Documents> $remote_var = '3333'
[RemoteServer]: PS C:\Users\user\Documents> Exit-PSSession
$nowLocalVar = Invoke-Command -Session $session { $remote_var }

